# Ubuntu Apache2 server appears to reject a certain domain name

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, domain-name-system, subdomain

I am using a Apache2 installed on Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail to host a small wallpapers website.  Originally I used osgwallpapers.servepics.com from no-ip.com for my domain name.  Now I'm trying to transfer it to wallpapers.osgalaxy.net  I own osgalaxy.net from freenames and it's working fine.  However, my subdomain (wallpapers.osgalaxy.net) fails to work.

I live chatted with the the friendly cheapnames customer support, and they told me that my server was rejecting the cheapnames domain names.  This is confirmed by the fact that `wget wallpapers.osgalaxy.net` outputs the following:

```
Resolving wallpapers.osgalaxy.net (wallpapers.osgalaxy.net) 144.124.222.81
Connecting to wallpapers.osgalaxy.net (wallpapers.osgalaxy.net) |144.142.222.81|:80...
```

It might say something eventually, but I don't bother to wait for it to time out.

It seems that I should need to change some configuration, but I never needed to do that for osgwallpapers.servepics.com

If anyone wants to try it out themselves, they can go to these urls.  osgwallpapers.servepics.com is my current url, and wallpapers.osgalaxy.com is my desired url.

How can I fix this problem?

BTW, if this is the wrong place to post this, please let me know.  I'm not totally clear whether a production webserver at home fits into the official Server fault scope or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's *another* typo in the IP address that domain resolves to. (In addition to the one created in the question when you updated `122` to `124` instead of `142`)

```
> dig +short osgwallpapers.servepics.com
114.142.222.81
> dig +short wallpapers.osgalaxy.net 
144.142.222.81
```

The first part of the IP should be `114` instead of `144`.

The reverse lookup of that IP address (`114-142-222-81.dsl.static.teleguam.net`) and the download speeds I'm achieving when browsing the site suggest that it's a domestic ADSL connection.  That might not be the best place to host a website, especially one hosting large, hi-res images.

Also, most of the navigation links point to `http://localhost/`. You'll want to fix that before you launch.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with my stupidness.  (I posted that last question at 1:00AM)  It works now.  Also thank you for pointing out the localhost link error.  (I think I am allowed to say this.)